# Prenex form of an expression: Cannot understand example

Tags: predicate-logic

My new course in this semester starts of with predicate-logic and on the way touches prenex form, quantifiers, skolemization and unification - all topics quite new for me. I do not start completely from scratch but with little previous knowledge.

For homework I need to solve an expression and noticed I barely understand the topic.

The first step in my assignment is finding the (better: a?) prenex form of the equation. I did study my schools script but it does not contain much information about the rules to manipulate quantized expressions so I researched more lecture material of others faculties. That helped a lot, but also brought me to an example I cannot grasp:

On page 134 of this [PDF](https://formal.iti.kit.edu/teaching/FormSysWS1516/skriptum.pdf) (that's page 148 in pdf pages) you find example 4.58 like this:
$$
1. \; \; \; ∀y \; (∀x \; ∀y \; p(x,y) → \; ∃x r(x,y)) \\
2. \; \; \; ∀y \; (∀x \; ∀z \; p(x,z) → \; ∃u r(u,y)) \\
3. \; \; \; ∀y \; ∃x \; (∀z \; p(x,z) → \; ∃u r(u,y)) \\
4. \; \; \; ∀y \; ∃x \; ∃z \; (p(x, z) → \; ∃u r(u,y)) \\
5. \; \; \; ∀y \; ∃x \; ∃z \; ∃u \; (p(x, z) → r(u,y))
$$
I do understand line 1 to line 2: name conflict in x and y is resolved by renaming y to z and x to u.
But line 2 to 3, and line 3 to 4 are a mystery to me. Why does pulling out the "all x"  change it to an "at least one x"? Same question for line 3 to 4, why does "all z" become a "one z"?

On the same page, above this example, there is an example mentioning that more than one prenex form can be transformed out of an equation
$$
∀x\;p(x) → ∀y\;q(y)
$$ can be transformed to
$$
∃x\;∀y\;(p(x) → q(y))
$$ as well as
$$
∀y\;∃x\;(p(x) → q(y))
$$ both of which I do not understand at all. Why doesn't it give
$$
∀x\;∀y\;(p(x) → q(y))
$$

Thanks for your help. I will post at least two other question regarding this homework assignment and relate them together as soon as they are posted.

Comment: See equivalences of page 126 (.pdf). The "conflicting" variables must be avoided in order to comply with the proviso of the necessary equivalences, i.e. that the qauntified variable is not free in the antecedent or consequent. E.g. $∀xA  → B$ is equivalent to $∃x(A → B)$, provided that $x \notin Free(B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prenex normal form basically is exploiting the following transforms (some of which require the standard non empty universe caveat):

$$B \land \forall x ~ A(x) = \forall x ~ (B \land A(x))$$
$$B \lor  \forall x ~ A(x) = \forall x ~ (B \lor A(x))$$
$$B \land \exists x ~ A(x) = \exists x ~ (B \land A(x))$$
$$B \lor  \exists x ~ A(x) = \exists x ~ (B \lor A(x))$$
$$ \lnot \exists x ~ A(x) = \forall x ~ \lnot A(x)$$
$$ \lnot \forall x ~ A(x) = \exists x ~ \lnot A(x)$$

So when converting to prenex, just write your equations as $\land$, $\lor$, and $\lnot$ and use the above transforms.

> $$2. \quad \forall y ~ (\forall x ~ \forall z ~ p(x,z) \implies \exists u~ r(u,y))$$

Rewrite the $\implies$ using $\lor$ and $\lnot$ :

$$\forall y ~ \boxed{ \boxed{\forall x \boxed{\forall z ~p(x,z)}}
                \implies \boxed{\exists u~ r(u,y)} }$$

$$\forall y ~ \boxed{ \lnot \boxed{\forall x \boxed{\forall z ~p(x,z)}}
                \lor \boxed{\exists u~ r(u,y)} }$$

Now use $ \lnot \forall x ~ A(x) = \exists x ~ \lnot A(x)$ a couple times to put the $\lnot$ inside of quantifiers:

$$\forall y ~ \boxed{ \boxed{ \exists x \lnot  \boxed{\forall z ~p(x,z)}}
                \lor \boxed{\exists u~ r(u,y)} } \tag{A}$$

$$\forall y ~ \boxed{ \boxed{ \exists x \boxed{\exists z ~\lnot p(x,z)}}
                \lor \boxed{\exists u~ r(u,y)} }$$

Now use $B \lor  \exists x ~ A(x) = \exists x ~ (B \lor A(x))$ a bunch of times to put the $\lor$ inside of quantifiers:

$$\forall y ~ \boxed{ \exists x \boxed{ \boxed{\exists z ~\lnot p(x,z)}
                \lor \boxed{\exists u~ r(u,y)} }} \tag{T}$$

$$\forall y ~ \boxed{ \exists x \boxed{\exists z \boxed{~\lnot p(x,z)
                \lor \boxed{\exists u~ r(u,y)} }}} \tag{C}$$

$$\forall y ~ \boxed{ \exists x \boxed{\exists z \boxed{ \boxed{\exists u~ r(u,y)}
                \lor \lnot p(x,z)  }}}$$

$$\forall y ~ \boxed{ \exists x \boxed{\exists z \boxed{ \exists u \boxed{ r(u,y)
                \lor \lnot p(x,z)  }}}}\tag{D}$$

And it is in prenex form.  **(B)** is equivalent to 3.  **(C)** is equivalent to 4.  **(D)** is equivalent to 5.

And occasionally shortcuts can be used to make the resulting prenex not so large:

$$\forall x ~ A(x) \land \forall y ~ B(y) = \forall z~A(z) \land B(z)$$
$$\exists x ~ A(x) \lor \exists y ~ B(y) = \exists z~A(z) \lor B(z)$$

A shortcut could have been used on step **(T)** to combine $z$ and $u$ into a single quantifier $w$:

$$\forall y ~ \boxed{ \exists x \boxed{ \boxed{\exists z ~\lnot p(x,z)}
                \lor \boxed{\exists u~ r(u,y)} }} \tag{T}$$

$$\forall y ~ \boxed{ \exists x \boxed{ \exists w \boxed{\lnot p(x,w)
                \lor r(w,y)} }} $$

And that is a much simpler prenex form.  Hopefully your book makes it clear that a single expression can have multiple prenex forms, as above.

Comment: Wow. Just wow. Quick question: In your explanation of possible shortenings regarding step (T), shouldn't example 2 be exist in all three cases?

Comment: I was able to follow up and understand this as you explained.   Somewhere in a text book I did read "quantifiers are pulled out to the left"... that is kind of true, but far more complex as I see now!  One more question: the first 4 transformations you give would allow B to contain some quantifier itself - just not in x, right?  B is however taken "as a whole" and in parentheses, so the quantifier of A "jumps in front"?    Since I am allowed to change order of A and B that is why I can have different prenex form out of an expression?!

Comment: Thanks for seeing the typo in the shortcut, I fixed it.  Yes, B can be an expression with quantifiers in it, but when it is the same quantifier as what A is contained in, then you probably want to use a shortcut, although you don't have to.  I was hoping that you would see that this actually isn't complicated.  It is just the observation that, since for any quantifier/boolean-operator pair the quantifier can be factored out (as I wrote at the start, possibly changing the quantifier and operator), then inductively every expression has a prenex form.

Comment: Why are there multiple prenex forms?  Well true or $\top$ is an equivalent prenex form for any true statement.  All true statements have the same set of equivalent prenex forms.  More generally, if $Y$ is the set of statements that are true under condition $X$, then all the prenex forms of $X$ are valid prenex forms of any statement in $Y$.  I've just shown you one algorithm to generate a prenex form, that doesn't make it unique.